# JSF 2 - CRUD and persistent support

Tags: jsf-2, crud

I'm in two minds at the moment in terms of adopting a persistence framework for CRUD operation (for MySQL) with JSF 2. I've googled and read comments from pro-JPA vs pro-JDO groups but I still can't decide what to adopt.

Is there any good step-by-step tutorials (similar to those provided at balusc.blogspot.com) of JPA implementations (Hibernate, etc) and JDO implementations (DataNucleas, etc) available online? Perhaps going through these examples might help me to understand a bit more about these two Java specifications and decide which to adopt finally.

I'm a newbie when it comes to JPA and JDO implementations so please be kind in your responses -:)...

P.S: Please no reference to roseindia.net. Sorry, that site is just too crappy for me!...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with maven archetype that should get you up to speed really fast.

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/projects/knappsack/

I suggest trying to use this one:
jee6-servlet-minimal-archetype

It gets you CDI+2.0+JPA

Comment: Thanks, mate, for your reply. I managed to figure it out after several days of writing/testing codes in Eclipse. I eventually settled with JPA 2 (EclipseLink implementation that is bundled with Glassfish 3.1), EJB 3 and JSF 2, of course.